# Is there an equivalent MessageFactory in C#?

Tags: c#

Help, Java has an interface for creating different messages called MessageFactory (org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MessageFactory namespace), are there any C # equivalents?

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make a lot of sense.  The `MessageFactory` you are talking about is not part of the Java SE APIs.  It is actually specific to the (3rd party!) Apache log4j 2.x APIs<sup>1</sup>.  The `Message` objects that it generates are wrappers for passing objects around (in memory!) in the logging system.  They don't make any sense outside of the log4j 2.x logging context.

So ... no, there isn't an equivalent in C# because log4j doesn't have a (single) equivalent in C#.  But if you chose a specific C# logging framework, it may have an equivalent.

But if you are asking this because you are trying to translate some Java code that uses log4j logging, you probably should be looking for a less "literal" way of translating it.

---

<sup>1 - But there was no `MessageFactory` in log4j 1.2.</sup>